Error instantiating bean of type [io.micronaut.data.mongodb.serde.DataCodecRegistryBuilder]
I'm developing a microservice using Micronaut and Kotlin, which connects to an EventStore and listens for associated events. These events are then stored in a local MongoDB database. The MongoDB integration is handled through a Helm package as a dependency of my microservice.
Recently, I extracted all the event packages into a core dependency. It works well in one microservice, but in another, it breaks with this stack trace error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error instantiating bean of type [io.micronaut.data.mongodb.serde.DataCodecRegistryBuilder]
Message: 'void io.micronaut.serde.support.serializers.ObjectSerializer.<init>(io.micronaut.serde.SerdeIntrospections, io.micronaut.serde.config.SerializationConfiguration, io.micronaut.context.BeanContext)'
Path Taken: MongoDatabaseNameProviderFactory.namedMongoDatabaseNameProvider(NamedMongoConfiguration mongoConfiguration,String server,BeanContext beanContext,RuntimeEntityRegistry runtimeEntityRegistry,SchemaTenantResolver tenantResolver) --> MongoDatabaseNameProviderFactory.namedMongoDatabaseNameProvider([NamedMongoConfiguration mongoConfiguration],String server,BeanContext beanContext,RuntimeEntityRegistry runtimeEntityRegistry,SchemaTenantResolver tenantResolver) --> NamedMongoConfiguration.setCodecRegistryBuilder([CodecRegistryBuilder codecRegistryBuilder]) --> new DataCodecRegistryBuilder(Environment environment,[DataSerdeRegistry dataSerdeRegistry],RuntimeEntityRegistry runtimeEntityRegistry)

Below is an excerpt from my build.gradle.kts file, including relevant dependencies:
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.22"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.9.22"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.9.22"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "4.3.4"
    id("io.micronaut.test-resources") version "4.3.4"
    id("com.google.cloud.tools.jib") version "3.4.0"
    id("io.micronaut.aot") version "4.3.4"
    id("org.sonarqube") version "4.3.1.3277"
    id("jacoco")
}
 
dependencies {
    api("com.perso.core:business-logic:0.0.23")
    api("com.perso.core:adapters:0.0.23")
 
    kapt("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    kapt("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi")
    kapt("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-processor")
    kapt("io.micronaut.validation:micronaut-validation-processor")
    kapt("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-document-processor")
 
    implementation("io.micrometer:context-propagation")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-extension-functions")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor")
    implementation("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-jackson")
    implementation("io.micronaut.validation:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.3")
    implementation("jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("com.eventstore:db-client-java:4.3.0")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-management")
 
    compileOnly("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    compileOnly("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi-annotations")
 
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    runtimeOnly("org.yaml:snakeyaml")
    runtimeOnly("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams")
 
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    testImplementation("org.hamcrest:hamcrest")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.testresources:micronaut-test-resources-extensions-junit-platform")
}
}
 

All my events are annotated with the @Serdeable annotation in my personal core library. The model that I try to map is also annotated with @Introspected and @Serdeable annotations in the present microservices.
Has anyone else encountered a similar issue with Micronaut and MongoDB integration? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

It's resolve by adding my personal core in the processing annotation :
micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.app.*", "com.perso.core.*")
    }
    aot {
    // Please review carefully the optimizations enabled below
    // Check https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-aot/latest/guide/ for more details
        optimizeServiceLoading.set(false)
        convertYamlToJava.set(false)
        precomputeOperations.set(true)
        cacheEnvironment.set(true)
        optimizeClassLoading.set(true)
        deduceEnvironment.set(true)
        optimizeNetty.set(true)
    }
}



